# multiple python lists to table rows in HTML

Tags: python, html

I have multiple lists created in python. I am trying to convert these lists into HTML rows.

```
week = ['1','2']
date = ['2022-10-01','2022-10-09']
```

My HTML table should look like below:

```
Week     Date
1        2022-10-01
2        2022-10-09
```

what I tried so far:

```html
{% for val in data %}
<tr>
  <td>
    {% for item in val.week %} {{ item }} <br> {% endfor %}
  </td>
  <td>
    {% for item in val.date %} {{ item }} <br> {% endfor %}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem with above code is every value is treated as cell instead of row and hence I am unable to apply any row related styles to the above.

Could someone help with how to convert these to rows instead of cells.

Thank you.

Comment: Will the length of both the lists be the same all the time?

Comment: Yes. Length would be same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension to convert the two lists into a dictionary where the key would be the week number and the value would be the corresponding date. You can loop over the dictionary as key and value using the items attribute in the template.

```
# views.py
week = [1, 2]
date = ['2022-10-01','2022-10-09']
data = {week[i]: date[i] for i in range(len(week))}
return render(request, 'template.html', {'data': data})


# template.html
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ key }} </td>
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this approch...

#### ------ views.py ------

```
week = ['1','2']
date = ['2022-10-01','2022-10-09']
data = tuple(zip(week,date))
```

#### ------ html ------

```
<table style="border: 1px solid;  border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
      <th>Weeks</th>
      <th>Dates</th>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
      <tbody>
        {% for i,j in data %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{i}}</td>
          <td>{{j}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </tbody>

  </table>
```

#### -------- Output -------

[image]